# Excel, vlookup from two columns

Tags: excel, vlookup

Can somebody explain me why it's not working?

Once I used it and worked.

[image: Screenshot from Excel with formula]

Comment: You need a column with the Name+Surname in the upper table.

Comment: In first table you should have `Name` and `Surname` in same column as `AB`,`CD`,`EF`,`...`.

Comment: No other possibility to make it from two columns?

Comment: @Lucas Not easily; using a single column is the best way. You could have this column in a separate, hidden sheet (along with the age column)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$6,MATCH(1,($A$1:$A$6=A11)*($B$1:$B$6=B11),0))
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Breaking this down, have I got this right? MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type]) match type = 0 so exact match($A$1:$A$6=A11) I'm assuming this is some sort of shorthand for true or false evaluating to 1 or 0. So true * true = 1*1 evaluating to lookup_value of 1. and match returns the positiion ie a row number or #N/A and that is fed into INDEX. I don't get why you can't specify column as 1 and not use array formula within INDEX(array, row_num, [column_num]). That doesn't seem to work

Comment: @JGFMK - In `MATCH(1,($A$1:$A$6=A11)*($B$1:$B$6=B11),0)`, `($A$1:$A$6=A11)*($B$1:$B$6=B11)` will give **lookup_array** containing `0 or 1`. `1` is **lookup_value** and is being matched with **match_type** `EXACT MATCH`.

Comment: Not quite getting it yet.  ($A$1:$A$6=A11) to me intuitively reads as find A11 in the range A1:A6. Don't know why it's wrapped in parentheses. The 'will give lookup_array' is part that's throwing me most.

Comment: @JGFMK - `($A$1:$A$6=A11)` is `({0;A;C;E;G;I}="C")`, which will give `({FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE})` and likewise `($B$1:$B$6=B11)` will give `({FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE})`. So `($A$1:$A$6=A11)*($B$1:$B$6=B11)` is nothing but `({FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE})*({FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE})` and gives `{0;0;1;0;0;0}`. Then `1` is looked for exact match in this array. I hope its clear now.

Comment: @JGFMK - You can use [**Evaluate Formula**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7) to see the calculation yourself.

Comment: Ah ok. Now it makes total sense. And consequently your original should have been for range A$2:A$6  and B$2:B$6 omitting the header row in the lookup data.

Comment: @JGFMK - Exactly, range could start from `A2` but i try to maintain the consistency of OP's formula as long as its does not give wrong results.