# VLOOKUP MULTIPLE RANGES

Tags: excel, vlookup

Column A and B is a item and country post code. Column B contain two country post code USA and UK. Both country we have dispatched same part. I am trying to create vlookup formula corresponding to the range but its return na. Please help me.

Country code ranges;

```
USA Angeles10   Angeles20   Angeles30   Angeles40   Angeles50   Angeles60   Angeles70   Angeles80   Angeles90   Angeles100  Angeles110  Angeles120  Angeles130  Angeles140  Angeles150
UK  London10    London20    London30    London40    London50    London60    London70    London80    London90    London100   London110   London120   London130   London140   London150
```

DATA

```
ITEM    POST CODE
4   Angeles10
4   Angeles20
110489  Angeles30
110489  Angeles40
113388  Angeles50
113388  Angeles60
113636  Angeles70
113636  Angeles80
11363613001 Angeles90
11363613001 Angeles100
11363613002 Angeles110
11363613002 Angeles120
11363613003 Angeles130
11363613003 Angeles140
1136362001  Angeles150
4   London10
4   London20
110489  London30
110489  London40
113388  London50
113388  London60
113636  London70
113636  London80
11363613001 London90
11363613001 London100
11363613002 London110
11363613002 London120
11363613003 London130
11363613003 London140
1136362001  London150
```

DESIRED RESULT

```
ITEM    USA         UK
4   Los Angeles10   London10
```

[image: Spreadsheet screenshot]

Comment: I think there is a way with markdown to format the content. See here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables - But it looks like a lot of work... I'll edit it so your image can at least be visible. You can do this in the future by using the symbol in the toolbar next to the {} symbol.

Comment: What exactly do you want to enter to get the result?

Comment: thanks for your advice and suggestion. I will follow-up in future.

Comment: You might also find Google sheets handy for linking an example too https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/

Comment: am trying to vlookup corresponding to the ranges. For example part number 4 we have dispatched both country. Please look at the country ranges.I am try to apply the following formula =VLOOKUP(D37&usa,CHOOSE({1,2},$A$2:$A$32,$A$2:$B$32,$B$2:$B$32),2,0) its return na. I have created name manger usa and uk ranges.

Comment: Did you try Scott Craners answer? He may have neglected to say you have to press CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER when you complete entering formula- Array formulas... https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7 This link might help a bit to understand his solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140773/495157

Comment: @JGFMK with aggregate one does not need Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: I have no idea what D37 represents as ti's off the image you posted...

Comment: Peters comment =VLOOKUP(D37 .... Sorry crossed wires! Should have used @PETER

Comment: @JGFMK I was frantically searching my post for the mistake.  I should have looked at the comments.  But still my comment stands, Ctrl-Shift-Enter is not needed as it is a native array formula like SUMPRODUCT and IRR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the first data on a sheet named `datasheet` in starting in A1.

[image]

Then use a formula like so in the E3:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$B$31)/((ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$2:$B$31,INDEX(datasheet!$1:$1048576,MATCH(E$2,datasheet!$A:$A,0),0),0)))*($A$2:$A$31=$D3)),1))
```

Then copy/drag over and down.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your Scott Craner . I have follow-up your formula its return #num!. please help me. how do resolve the issue

Comment: thank for the alternative solution HaveSpacesuit. I follow-up scott its return #num!. please help me.

Comment: I don't know.  Look at the data.  Make sure the ranges are all pointing at the correct location.  for ex `datasheet` needs to point to the sheet where you have the data.  Mine is named `datasheet` yours is probably not.  @PETER

Comment: thank you so much for your quick clarification. yes I made a mistake. your formula working fine. thanks a lot. you are genius.

Answer (score 0):

**Easiset Answer**

If your data isn't changing and you know exactly where Angeles stops and London starts, you can just use a standard `VLOOKUP` formula. You just give the bottom part of the table to the UK column.

E3: `=VLOOKUP(D3,A$3:B$6,2,)`

F3: `=VLOOKUP(D3,A$7:B$10,2,)`

[image]

**A little more complicated**

If you need to be able to add rows or locations, this solution will work better. Add helper columns for each of the locations you need and a helper column which combines the item ID with the location. You can then use `VLOOKUP` by searching for the combination of item ID and location.

B3: `=A3&CONCAT(D3:E3)` (can expand past `E3` for extra locations)

D3: `=IF(ISERR(SEARCH(D$2,$C3)),"",D$2)`

E3: `=IF(ISERR(SEARCH(E$2,$C3)),"",E$2)` (can drag right for each extra location)

H3: `=VLOOKUP($G3&H$2,$B$3:$C$10,2,)`

I3: `=VLOOKUP($G3&I$2,$B$3:$C$10,2,)` (can drag right for each extra location)

[image]

**My favorite Answer**

Just use Scott Craner's approach! ☺

Comment: Scott craner's formula working fine but return lookup first value only. I need a lookup second value. Please help me.